# plugin for com_modules is getting installed but no execution

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to create the plugin for com_modules so that whenever the save is triggered plugin has to perform two activities i.e. before save and after save.

Somehow I've created the plugin.. and activated too.

```
mywebsite.com/plugins/modules/myplugin.php 
mywebsite.com/plugins/modules/myplugin.xml
```

But it's not getting executed even the class... I've made the errors in myplugin.php but even those are not showing up any errors on the website.

Can you guide me how can I get rid of this problem or am I doing something wrong ?

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
// Load the Joomla Plugin
jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );


$GLOBALS[context]="com_modules.module";
//ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 
class plgModulesMyplugin extends JPlugin{


// edit here first
    public function onExtensionBeforeSave($context, $table, $isNew)
    {
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for both files you mentioned above?

Comment: its updated in question

Comment: As i understand you are defining your custom plugin group, It may be the problem with custom group. Try to make your plugin with any of default Joomla group like `system` etc, the it will work.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. atleast class is getting executed .And now I don't know how to trigger the beforesave and aftersave. I should be able to validate beforesave and aftersave but i believe the function name is not correct.

Comment: please update if anyone gets something working

Comment: My understanding would be that you still use onContentBeforeSave and onContentAfterSave and make this a "Content" plugin. Then check the context that is set to see if it is related to a module and not an article or another component.

Comment: that'll work only if its content component. I want to make the plugin for com_modules which is required to be executed when module is saved each time.. so that's why i need to know the name of the trigger/function like its doing it for content i.e. onContentBeforeSave

Answer (score 0):

Joomla plugins are executed depending on a particular event. If your plugin does not work it might be due to the reason that you plugin does not bind the event correctly. 1st make sure that the event is hit by the plugin.

Comment: I've made the plugins previously too. they worked without any issue. This is my first time that I am creating the plugin for com_modules  so just wondering if that's supported or not. because I haven't seen any plugins for modules created.

Comment: Moreover the trigger will happen only when the plugin is executed.. Class is not getting executed even I've made the php errors, exits, print_r but nothing is happening.